# how to automatically fill a One2many

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I am currently using the native module of odoo [Sales] -sales orders and I want to pass the registration of a One2many field at the moment of pressing the button that redirects me to another new formula that I have created and has a field One2Mnay.

example:
    this is the native module of odo where I am registering my sales orders:
[image]

I have created a new botton that is red says [registrar cotizacion] , 
called method: [open_budget] which allows to open a new form that I created and has a field one2many :

My models :

Models of new form :

```
class BudgetTwo(models.Model):
    _name = 'budget.two'
    name = fields.Char(string ='Nombre', copy=False, index=True ,default ="Nuevo")
    partner_id =fields.Many2one('res.partner' ,string ='Cliente', copy=False, index=True,required=True)
    deliver_date = fields.Date(string ='Fecha de Entrega')
    expiration_date = fields.Date(string ='Fecha de expiración')
    pay_place =fields.Many2one('account.payment.term' ,string='Plazo de Pago')
    order_line = fields.One2many('budget.table','budget_id' ,string = 'Pedidos' )
    total = fields.Float(string = 'Total:' ,compute="_total")
    btn_d = fields.Boolean(default = False)
```

Inheritance of the odoo's own module:

```
class InheritOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    @api.multi
    def open_budget(self):
        if self.order_line:
            for element in self.order_line:
                data = element.product_id.id
        else:print('none')
        print(data)

        return {
            'name': ('Payments'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'budget.two',
            'view_id': False,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'context': {
                'default_partner_id': self.partner_id.id,
                'default_order_line.product_id': data,
                'default_order_line.product_id': data,
            },
        }
```

the native module of odoo has a field One2many that are the orders, when I press the new botton loogre redirect to the new form that I created and created a dictionary which has a key called context I can pass the records that I have in the fields but the record that I have in the one2many values ​​are not passed.

Finally :

```
'context': {
                'default_partner_id': self.partner_id.id,
                'default_order_line.product_id': data,
                'default_order_line.product_id': data,
            },
```

desauld_pernert_id if the record passes but default_order_line.product_id does not pass the record that is the on2many, as you can see:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
class InheritOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    @api.multi
    def open_budget(self):
        ctx = dict()
        if self.order_line:
           products={}
           for line in self.order_line:
               # You can get whatever field from sale order line
               products.update({'product_id': line.product_id.id})
               product_line.append((0, 0, products))

           ctx.update({
                'default_order_line': product_line,
                'default_partner_id': self.partner_id.id,
             })

        return {
            'name': ('Payments'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'budget.two',
            'view_id': False,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'context': ctx,
          }
```

Comment: thansk this's solution friend

Answer (score 0):

There is a special syntax to pass values to [x2many fields](https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/x2many.html#x2many-values-filling).

If you want to create new lines you should use:

```
'context': {
            'default_partner_id': self.partner_id.id,
            'default_order_line.product_id': [(0, 0, {'field_name': its value,..}),
                                               ..., 
                                              (0, 0, {'field_name': its value, ..})
                                             ]
           },
```